# Spring batch : get actual item in write error listener while using Async item processor

Tags: asynchronous, listener, spring-batch, future

**Application background:**
I am using async item processor and passing delegate as composite processor. When i get an exception in processors, my write error listener gets called.

onWriteError method signature is (Exception exception, List items)

**Issue:** 
All items on the list to onWriteError method are Future tasks. If i call "get" method on future task, it gives me the same exception which caused write error.

How can i get the original item in writer listener methods during async execution?

I couldn't provide any actual code because my company policy prohibits me from posting code in online forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  It's like going back in time.  That is one of the disadvantages of the `AsyncItemProcessor/AsyncItemWriter` combination.  As the javadoc points out in the [`AsyncItemProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html):

> Because the Future is typically unwrapped in the ItemWriter, there are
>   lifecycle and stats limitations (since the framework doesn't know what
>   the result of the processor is). While not an exhaustive list, things
>   like StepExecution.filterCount will not reflect the number of filtered
>   items and ItemProcessListener.onProcessError(Object, Exception) will
>   not be called.